# Manutenção Osticket no PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, encontro um grande problema em um projeto qual fui designado, preciso acrescentar uma funcionalidade em uma ferramenta de chamados qual já esta em produção.

Seguindo o seguinte raciocínio tenho um form em HTML, onde o action encaminha para script PHP fazer as validações e inserir os dados no banco.

Inspecionando o formulário não consigo compreender para onde o action está apontando.

```
<form method="post" name="status" id="status" action="#tickets/status/open">
```

Answer (score 0):

O # aponta para uma div, verifique o diretorio, pois provavelmente ele está apontando para o caminho tickets/status/ open.

Comment: Poise, a primeira coisa que procurei foi uma `<div id=" ">`, porem não obtive sucesso. Em relação ao diretório também, nada que apresente o caminho: **tickets/status/open**.